# set input value to file located on server

Tags: amazon-s3, file-io, server-to-server

Ok im really new to amazon s3 just created my account today. im tring to upload files from my server to my S3 account via POST Proposal. i got at working form that has a input type file but i dont wanna select file form my computer. i want to create a cron job that submits a file located on my server. is this possible

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Unix/Linux, you may try to use command line s3 tools such as [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd). You will need pre-configure it and then you may put it into the cron:

```
s3cmd put ./file_name.tar.gz s3://bucket_name/subdirectory/
```

If you are on Windows and need GUI client you may consider [S3 Browser](http://s3browser.com)